# Why spacebar is not working after I put the uppercase method?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I decided to put a method to auto caps lock the field. But, after I put the uppercase method, the spacebar was disable to use

```
function testKod() {

   upperCase('#myKod'); //line I just add
   $('#myKod').textbox('textbox').attr({
   maxlength : 20
   });
}
```

The uppercase method is working but how to make the spacebar enable or it is has another way to declare the uppercase?

Comment: `upperCase` ... so that's a function you wrote? and it causes your code to stop working correctly (i.e. `space` is *disabled*) ... so, clearly `The uppercase method is working` is a bad assumption

Comment: Also, your description on what you're trying to do is very unclear.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation, because I am newbie and I dont know how to explain from a perception of a programmer

Comment: OK, tip #1 - the code in `upperCase` is moist likely the problem - without seeing the code, it's unlikely anyone can help. The code you have posted makes no sense with regard to your apparent problem